# How to get username inside CustomPasswordEncoder in SpringSecurity?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-security, passwords, bcrypt

I am introducing Spring Security in an existing application. Currently db has MD5 encoded passwords which we want to migrate to bcrypt. Since we have a large number of users initially we would like to support both MD5 and bcrypt together. We have thought off having a table which will store how many users are migrated to bcrypt once we have every one migrated we will stop supporting MD5.

So I thought of extending the **BCryptPasswordEncoder** class of SpringSecurity and do the things inside matches method. So I have below class,

```
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

public class CustomPasswordEncoder extends BCryptPasswordEncoder {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword) {
        if (rawPassword == null || encodedPassword == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!super.matches(rawPassword, encodedPassword)) { // This is not BCrypt password try OLD password encoding instead
            boolean isOldPasswordMatched = rawPassword.equals(SHA1.getSHA1Hash(encodedPassword));
            if(isOldPasswordMatched){
                migrateToBCrypt(userName /* error here*/, encode(rawPassword));
            }
            return isOldPasswordMatched;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean migrateToBCrypt(String userName, String newBcryptPassword){
        //update password in database 
        //Insert to migrated table
        return true;
    } 
}
```

However my problem is I don't get username inside this function to do the migration, **How can I get username inside matches() of password encoder ? Am I doing something wrong here ? What could be the best approach in this situation ?**

Comment: @user1354678 : The author is unable to get the user itself currently, how do you expect him/her to check for passwordType when username itself is unknown?

Comment: @user1354678 I am not able to get userName inside this function

Comment: @aProgrammer, I've proposed an answer, take a look at it

Comment: @user1354678 Curently I don't have a userService class implementation in my setup. So will try that tomorrow I will also have to figure out some way to convert your answer to XML configuration. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proposed logic is just my idea, you can modify it as per your needs.

```
public class UserService extends BCryptPasswordEncoder{

    public Response login(@RequestBody User user){

        User existingUser = UserDao.getInstance().getUserByUsername( user.getUsername() );

        //Assuming all the users have `PasswordType` column as "MD5" in user table
        if( existingUser.getPasswordType().equals("MD5") ){
                // Your MD5 verification method, return boolean
            if( verifyMD5(user.getPassword, existingUser.getPassword()) ){
                 migrateToBCrypt(existingUser, user);
                 return Response.status(200).entity("Successfully Logged in").build();
            }else{
                 return Response.status(400).entity("Invalid Credentials").build();
            }

        }else if( existingUser.getPasswordType().equals("BCrypt") ){

            if( matches(user.getPassword(), existingUser.getPassword()) ){
                return Response.status(200).entity("Successfully Logged in").build();
            }else{
                return Response.status(400).entity("Invalid Credentials").build();
            }

        }

    }

    private void migrateToBcrypt(User existingUser, User user){

        existingUser.setPassword( encode(user.getPassword()) );
        existingUser.setPasswordType( "Bcrypt" );
        UserDao.getInstance().updateUser( existingUser );

    }

}
```

Or if you don't want to introduce another column on table,

```
public class UserService extends BCryptPasswordEncoder{

    public Response login(@RequestBody User user){

        User existingUser = UserDao.getInstance().getUserByUsername( user.getUsername() );

        if( !existingUser.getPassword().startsWith("$") ){
                // Your MD5 verification method, return boolean
            if( verifyMD5(user.getPassword, existingUser.getPassword()) ){
                 migrateToBCrypt(existingUser, user);
                 return Response.status(200).entity("Successfully Logged in").build();
            }else{
                 return Response.status(400).entity("Invalid Credentials").build();
            }

        }else {

            if( matches(user.getPassword(), existingUser.getPassword()) ){
                return Response.status(200).entity("Successfully Logged in").build();
            }else{
                return Response.status(400).entity("Invalid Credentials").build();
            }

        }

    }

    private void migrateToBcrypt(User existingUser, User user){

        existingUser.setPassword( encode(user.getPassword()) );
        UserDao.getInstance().updateUser( existingUser );

    }

}
```